# How come Javascript it Broken in IE on my site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, modernizr

Here's the site: http://designsweeter.com/
It work sin all browsers but IE (any version, including 9).
I'm using jQuery, Modernizr, and slidesJs.
But none of my javascript is working. Any clue why?
Here's the js file: http://designsweeter.com/scripts.js

Unminified (same order they are in my js file):

modernizr: http://www.modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr-2.0.6.js
jquery 1.6: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.js
jquery easing: http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js
slidesjs: http://designsweeter.com/non-packed-js/slides.js
jQuery Smooth Scroll:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a.topLink").click(function() {
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top + "px"
        }, {
            duration: 500,
            easing: "swing"
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Wow. I'd love to look at an unminified Javascript. Also what have you tried so far? Do you have any suspicions?

Comment: Is there anything in the error console?

Comment: Oh, I'll post unminified, hold on.

Comment: I only have IE 7, no error console. I checked other versions with an online site. Microsoft won't let me own other versions of IE, if I upgrade it says I need a service pack, but upon downloading the service pack, ti says I don't need the service pack and to continue not having. :/

Comment: It's a little bit difficult to troubleshoot because the styles are mixed in with your markup. One thing I would start with is moving all your styles out of your tags and into your stylesheet - it's a lot easier to troubleshoot. I don't think the problem here is javascript, I think it's the layout. I think you might want to restructure the way you're accomplishing it - start with wrapping your content in a div, give it a width, and center it with margin: 0 auto; This will give you better cross-browser results than using the absolute positioning and large left margins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:
scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top + "px"

; Baby!

; is missing at the end of the line. I bet your unminified code will work on IE too.

Comment: Must've just been a simple typing error. I never saw it, and strangely enough, my error-checker never caught it either. Thanks.

Comment: In JavaScript ; are not necessary as the browser's JavaScript interpreter inserts it. But that fails when you minimize the code.

Answer (score 0):

When I visit your site in Chrome I get a bunch of console.log information. try removing all console.log() code (it's not supported in IE so it'll break all your javascript).

Alternatively you could add this code to the top of your page to handle any browser that doesn't support console.log().

```
if(typeof(console) === 'undefined') {
    console = {}
}
```